# Creating a row with joined data in one query, sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables: **Item** and **User**.

```
export const Item = sequelize.define('item', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true}
})

export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    email: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true}
})
```

They are associated:

```
User.hasOne(Item)
Item.belongsTo(User)
```

I want sequelize to create a row in the **item** table, but i have only email of **user**. Can i pass the email instead of userId and create an item in one query without User.findOne?

I didn't try anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know an id of a user that should be liked to a new `item` record so you need to have a user id one way or another on your hands and pass it as `userId` value of `Item`. The `Item` association knows nothing about user's email.
The only way you can have only user's email while creating an `Item` record is when you're crating a user along with an item.